# Using variables in CURL

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm using curl to submit a file unto Skyling and then get the output provided by the site (following this: http://skylign.org/help#api_docs ).

I would want to use a variable file input, and not have the write the file each time directly on the code.

When I write the file (hmmfile.hmm) directly onto the code the output is the one expected. But when I set a variable (HMM) and use the variable as my file then the putput is blank.

This works:

```
curl -H 'Accept:application/json' -F file='@hmmfile.hmm' -F processing=hmm http://skylign.org
```

This doesn't:

```
HMM=$1

curl -H 'Accept:application/json' -F file="${HMM}" -F processing=hmm http://skylign.org
```

The output should be something like this:

```
"url":"http://skylign.org:8000/logo/6BBFEB96-E7E0-11E2-A243-DF86A4A34227",
  "uuid":"6BBFEB96-E7E0-11E2-A243-DF86A4A34227",
  "message":"Logo generated successfully"
```

Comment: if $1 doesn't have @ at the beginning it's not gonna work, you must prefix the filename with an @ sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try…

```
HMM=$1

curl -H 'Accept:application/json' -F file=@"${HMM}" -F processing=hmm http://skylign.org
#                                         ^
#                                         |
#                                         |
```

The `@` is needed as it tells `curl` the field is a file upload.